# How I can display data with *ngFor after get request

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm making my pet-project and have some troubles with front-end. Here you can see my code when main page loads:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.preRequest();
  }

preRequest()
  {
    this.authService.getLocation().then(pos=>
      {
          this.lng = pos.lng;
          this.lat = pos.lat;

          let options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-RapidAPI-Key', 'keyforapirequest')
            .set('X-RapidAPI-Host', 'travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com')
        };

        let str = `https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-by-latlng?latitude=${this.lat}&longitude=${this.lng}&limit=9&offset=${this.offset}`;
        console.log(str);

        this.http.get(str, options).subscribe((response: any) => 
                {
                    this.resultSummary = response.paging.total_results;
                    this.dataResponse = response;
                    this.dataResponse.data = response.data.filter(item => "name" in item );
                    console.log(this.dataResponse);
                });
      });
  }
```

here I call function that makes a get request and inserts longitude and latitude of current user to get specific data and also here are limit of response elements and offset property that allows to get certain part of elements from whole list which I use for pagination:

```
next()
  {
    if((this.offset + 9) <= this.resultSummary)
    {
      this.offset = this.offset + 9;
      this.preRequest();
    }
  }

  previous()
  {
    if((this.offset - 9) >= 0)
    {
      this.offset = this.offset - 9;
      this.preRequest();
    }
  }
```

Data by itself is stored in variable for mapping in html file with *ngFor:

```
<section style="width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; height: 730px; width: 99%;" class="row">
        <ng-container class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let item of dataResponse.data; let i = index">
            <div style="margin-left: 11%; margin-top: 2%;" class="card">
                <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\'' + this.getImage() + '\')'}" class="card-image card-context"></div>
                <h2 style="align-self: center;" [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': checkString(item.name)}">
                    {{item.name}}
                </h2>
                <ng-rating-bar 
                style="align-self: center;"
                *ngIf="checkFunc(item) === true"
                [(value)]="item.rating" 
                [ratingCount]="5" 
                ></ng-rating-bar>
                <p style="font-weight: 350; font-size: 18px; align-self: center;" *ngIf="checkFunc(item) === false">
                    Not rated yet
                </p>
                <p style="font-weight: 350; font-size: 24px; align-self: center;">Price level</p>
                <ngb-progressbar
                *ngIf="checkPrice(item.price_level) !== 0"
                style="margin: 2%;"
                type="{{pbarColor(item.price_level)}}"
                [max]="100"
                [value]="checkPrice(item.price_level)"
                height="15px"
                ></ngb-progressbar>
                <p style="font-weight: 350; font-size: 18px; align-self: center;" *ngIf="checkPrice(item.price_level) === 0">
                    Not researched yet
                </p>
                <button class="btn">More</button>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
        
        <div class="flex">
            <ul>
                <a (click)="previous()"><li style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 28px"><</li></a>
                <li class="linkDefault">1</li>
                <p>...</p>
                <li class="linkDefault">4</li>
                <li class="linkDefault">5</li>
                <li class="linkDefault">6</li>
                <p>...</p>
                <li class="linkDefault">9</li>
                <a (click)="next()"><li style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 28px">></li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>
```

Here is a full code of this html file of component which displays that data. All is fine when I set preRequest() function in ngOnInint() or even when I call it by specific way by button press after page was loaded. But when I click button of pagination that triggers next() or previous() function where new request happens with new offset, all data in such case become lost and new data that comes don't display with *ngFor, but instead of it, it shows only empty fields. I tried some ways to solve it. Firstly, I had found one possible solution to use *ngIf to cause a rerender of component, I inserted *ngIf in  tag, and made a variable that turned variable to false and back to true state in next() and previous() , but it didn't help:

```
next()
  {
    if((this.offset + 9) <= this.resultSummary)
    {
      this.offset = this.offset + 9;
      this.refreshState = false;
      this.preRequest();
      setTimeout(() => this.refreshState = true);
    }
  }

  previous()
  {
    if((this.offset - 9) >= 0)
    {
      this.offset = this.offset - 9;
      this.refreshState = false;
      this.preRequest();
      setTimeout(() => this.refreshState = true);
    }
  }
```

Also another possible solution was about to make *ngFor execution async, I made it something like that:

```
<ng-container #container class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let item of this.dataResponse.data | async; let i = index">
```

But this "solution" that I found made it even worse and data didn't load. I hope that I exaplined porblem properly, thanks everyone who will respond

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll answer with some cookie-cutter code you can just use anywhere. I suspect the real answer lies with how you're trying to make your request and then get the response...

What follows is a basic setup where, when your component tells your service to get data, it will fire off the request and immediately subscribe to the request itself.

This keeps all request handling inside the service rather than in the component. The component - and any other components that may want to know about this data - can just set up a subscription to the service's obs when it initialises and wait for data to be emitted. Once emitted, it can do something with it.

It also simplifies usage, so you're not doing things like `this.service.getData().subscribe((x) => {...});` a million times throughout your component whenever you want to make that call again.

Set up (on init) once, and have it tear down (unsub) once on destroy.

`some.service.ts`

```
export class SomeService {
    private obs: Observer<any>;

    private _data$: Observable<any>();
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this._data$ = new Observable((x: Observer<any>) => {this.obs = x;}).pipe(share());
    }

    public get data$(): Observable<any> { return this._data$; }

    public getData(): void {
        const sub = this.http.get('some url')
            .subscribe({
                next: (response: any) => { this.obs?.next(response); },
                error: (err) => {
                    console.error('request failed: ', err);
                    this.obs?.next(undefined);
                }
            });
    }
{
```

`some.component.ts`

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subs: Subscription[] = [];

    private _data: any;

    constructor(private readonly service: SomeService) {}

    public get data(): any { return this._data; }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subs.push(this.service.data$
            .subscribe((x: any) => this.onDataResponse(x)));

        this.service.getData();
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subs.forEach((x: Subscription) => x.unsubscribe());
    }

    private onDataResponse(data: any): void {
        this._data = data;
    }
}
```

This component can refresh the data at any point by just calling `this.service.getData()` again whenever it feels like it. Or, if another component calls that from some other part of your app, then this component will get the fresh data when it gets emitted so that everyone stays in sync with what the state of this data is!

`some.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="data">
    Yay we have data.
</div>
```

Obviously, you don't have to write it all out long form - I have a habit of *not* making everything public, and frequently use getters with backing fields because why are you touching my stuff? Just shut up and listen, no touchy.

Specifically for your question, that `any` response could well be `number[]` or anything else (thus `any` - hopefully you're actually using the full typing capabilities so kindly provided by TS. I mean, it's in the name... *Type*Script).

Assuming `data` is therefore an array of something, maybe just a list of numbers, `number[]`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    Some number: {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, by the way, I have solved problem by new value assignment to variable and it started to show new data:

`next()
  {
    if((this.offset + 9) <= this.resultSummary)
    {
      this.offset = this.offset + 9;
      this.counter = -1;
      this.dataResponse = [];
      this.preRequest();
    }
  }`

Also I mentioned your recomendations and grateful to you for them, I'll make my code more strongly typized and according to oop principles